# SOQL Query to get attachments which contains record name

Tags: soql

I am trying to query all the attachments on parent object from child record where attachment name contains child record name

Can any one help me on this

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment WHERE Parent_Object__c = :ParentrecordId AND Name LIKE '%childrecordname%'`